# Change image for music library folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, music-management

With the Windows 7 Music Library in "Folder" view each subfolder will be rendered as a "page" and some pages will have an image of the album/CD cover.

But how can I change this image? Some CDs are published with different covers over time or in different countries etc.

Right clicking on the folder doesn't reveal any options and opening the folder shows only the tracks within and no kind of metadata for the image used.

Where is this image stored? Is it part of Windows Media Player? What happens on systems without Windows Media Player installed?

Answer (score 4):

1. Open the music folder
2. Select Organize from the top menu
3. Select Folder and Search Options
4. Select the View tab
5. Uncheck "Hide Protected Operating System Files" and check "Show Hidden Files"
6. Click "OK"

Now you will be able to see the individual picture files that are used in the folder preview. You can modify or change them however you would like.

Comment: Thanks Paxamime and Soumya92! Is this documented somewhere? I would be interested to know if the sizes of the images are specific, if formats other than `.jpg` can be used, and if the GUID {6E2EE6EC-3AA4-41B7-88A6-D249ADDF1F05} has some special meaning.

Comment: I don't think formats other than .jpg can be used. The GUID is album specific. There is a program that can pull it from music files, can't remember it offhand.

Comment: Sorry to unaccept the answer but after replacing the four images with correct ones edited to the same dimensions with GIMP the images reverted while I was listening to the album in Windows Media Player - not even connected to the internet at the time! There must be some magic with the GUIDs or cached in Windows Media Player or the registry...

Comment: It is reverting them because you have Windows Media Player set to download updated media content. You need to remove this setting for it to keep from grabbing the updated picture.